# Nodemailer is not sending emails in NestJs

Tags: javascript, nestjs, nodemailer

I have the next configuration for nodemailer package:

```js
//App module 
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        secure: false,
      },
      defaults: {
        from: '"nest-modules" <modules@nestjs.com>',
      },
      template: {
        dir: __dirname + '/templates',
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
        options: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
    }),
   ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And

```js
//Email service 
export class EmailService {
  constructor(private readonly mailerService: MailerService) {}

  public example(): void {
    this.mailerService
      .sendMail({
        to: 'email@gmail.com', // list of receivers
        from: 'test@nestjs.com', // sender address
        subject: 'Testing Nest MailerModule ✔', // Subject line
        text: 'welcome', // plaintext body
        html: '<b>welcome</b>', // HTML body content
      })
      .then((r) => {
        console.log(r, 'email is sent');
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e, 'error sending email');
      });
  }
}
```

I am using my local environement. Tring the code above i get an error in catch block: `Error: Greeting never received`. Why i get that error and how to send the email without any issue?

Comment: Do you have a local SMTP server running? That actually can send mails?

Comment: @JeremyThille, could you explain what is this? because i am new on node js.

Answer (score 0):

1. This code means

```js
MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        secure: false,
      },
```

nodemailer try to find SMTP mail transfer agent (relay) listening on localhost:3000.
Its unlikely there is SMTP server on your machine on 3000 port, so most likely nodemailer cannot receive confirmation from anything on your 3000 port that it is SMTP server and throws error you mentioned.

2. Try using this transport for nodemailer, it can work without SMTP relay
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-direct-transport

Code will be something like this:

```js
import {directTransport} from 'nodemailer-direct-transport';

//App module 
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: directTransport({}),
      defaults: {
        from: '"nest-modules" <modules@nestjs.com>',
      },
      template: {
        dir: __dirname + '/templates',
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
        options: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
    }),
   ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: if i add directTransport, i get `TypeError: (0 , nodemailer_direct_transport_1.directTransport) is not a function`. NOTE: i instaled the package

Comment: how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you just wanna send an email using local SMTP or send an email in any SMTP  available

if it's the latter you can use google SMTP or mailtrap.No need to set up SMTP server. The configuration will be

```
    MailerModule.forRoot({
   transport: {
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: "465",
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: "your_gmail_email",
            pass: "your_gmail_app_password"
          }
           }
         })
      // or for mailtrap.io 
       const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
         host: 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
         port: 2525,
         auth: {
             user: "<user>",
             pass: "<pass>"
         }
 })
```

In the case of a local SMTP server, you can check [smtp-server](https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-server/)
to create an SMTP server or [MaiDev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/maildev) will help you to set up an SMTP server locally. MailDev has also available via docker that would be easier too.